# Web3: How do I get just the first account on testrpc using web3.eth.getAccounts()?

Tags: web3js, testrpc, accounts, console

When I run this code in web3

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => console.log(e));
```

The console returns this:

```
 [ '0x772f437b0f15e1F205C8BD923b5C8357e9c0c429',
    '0x5738d9100A6CB64FB78730746ab61472c7808fD9',
    '0x7086D052EAaD359c7aCD9B993c6169aE0dEC0725',
    '0x9fA18751b024FDC55cC85A484fF4261351Dd4666',
    '0x95a29de4A8cc4697E627922d270Aa74C2bd7494a',
    '0x332c22e9c7F02e092b18C6cc4D9Bfd46d36Dd7D9',
    '0xaED2F48c0d06a13D1FE2853E7Ee3B7d0aA328d3B',
    '0x88A0941f0dcb501C20b7BaE5a41608EB981f1209',
    '0xad5d1cB78e80518b596A814340826F36B89660Fc',
    '0x67E23e936C9d22eDCf9ebC9A989911b313c24BC1' ]
```

But what if I only want the first account in the array and assign it to a variable?

In this case, it's *0x772f437b0f15e1F205C8BD923b5C8357e9c0c429*

**EDIT:**

I have got the correct output after following the instruction of István András Seres, below is my code:

```
var firstAccount;

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => { 
 firstAccount = e[0];
 console.log("A: " + firstAccount);
}) 

console.log("B: " + firstAccount);
```

Strangely, the output is:

```
A: [correct testrpc account]

B: undefined
```

It seems that a variable is not allowed to carry the same value once it exits getAccounts() function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns a list of addresses you can access the first accounts's address easily just by `e[0]` in your example.

So just try this: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => let firstAcc=e[0]; console.log(firstAcc));`

Have a look at the official documentation of the `getAccounts()` web3js function [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getaccounts#getaccounts).

Comment: Hi Istvan, I got the desired output on the terminal. However, it seems that the variable firstAcc resets its own value once the program exits the getAccounts() function (See the EDIT for reference). The web3.js documentation doesn't seem to explain why that is the case. Is there a way to overcome this problem? Sorry for asking such basic question, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: This is not a web3.js related issue rather just a regular javascript phenomena. The function which body is after the .then is called the callback function. In your edited question first the second console.log is executed and at the time of its execution indeed firstAccount is undefined, this is no surprise! However, when the callback function is returned and executed, obviously we will have the correct value in the firstAccount variable. I guess you should just get to know better callback functions. You could start at thousand places, there are plenty of good resources for Javascript

Comment: A more interesting question is, how do you get the 11th account address if you have 11+ accounts?

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts((err, res) => {accounts = res[0]})

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
var address = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

to get the first address in in curret account

Comment: I believe "web3.eth.accounts" has been deprecated, no? In any case, it did not return the first account. When I print it on the console, it says "undefined." Thanks for answering though.

Comment: web3.eth.accounts[0]; definitively return the first account address.

Comment: @btc4cash No it doesn't.

Comment: Prove it please!

Comment: @btc4cash, John is saying right so don't argu if you are not sure about your answer.

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts((err, res) => {accounts = res[0]})

Answer (score 2):

It is very important to take note of the version of web3 you are using because there are changes to be reckoned with!

**CASE 1: web3.js 0.2x.x (Stable)**

For web3 0.2x.x https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts

```
var address = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

and the async (asynchronous) version can be used,

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(callback(error, result){ ... });
```

They are both read-only and return a list (i.e. Array) of accounts the node controls.

**Here is the Problem:**

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => console.log(e));
```

will fail because getAccounts implements a **callback** not a **promise**.

**CASE 2: web3.js 1.0 ( A work in Progress)**

getAccounts returns **Promise** which returns Array - An array of addresses controlled by node.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts Supports both Promise and Callback

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(callback(error, result){ ... }); // callback
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => console.log(e)); // Promise
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Truffle Console**

`web3.eth.getAccounts().then( function(s){FirstA=s[0]})`

then You can use FirstA variable

`FirstA`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

style in geth command window to get the account.

You should use

```
web3.eth.getAccounts()
```

style in Node JS to get the account.

Comment: first one works in web3 0.20.x, second one is used in web3 1.0.x

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for an easy answer:

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
```

will assign whole array to `accounts`. Then you can access as `accounts[0]` to the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){accounts=acc;});
accounts[0];
```

Note: I'm using truffle console.